# Can't Extract Data from SOAP Response

Tags: php, soap

I have been working on a SOAP request / response using CURL with PHP, however I can't seem to work out how to extract the Data for the life of me.

**Script for SOAP Request**

```
$soapUrl        = "https://xml.proveid.experian.com/IDSearch.cfc?wdsl";     

// xml post structure

    $xml_post_string = "<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
                        <soapenv:Envelope xmlns:xsi='http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance' xmlns:xsd='http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema' xmlns:soapenv='http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/' xmlns:cor='http://corpwsdl.oneninetwo'>
                        <soapenv:Header/>
                          <soapenv:Body>
                          <cor:search soapenv:encodingStyle='http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/'>
                             <xml xsi:type='xsd:string'><![CDATA[
                                <Search xmlns:xsd='https://xml.proveid.experian.com/xsd/Search.xsd'>
                                    <Authentication>
                                        <Username>".$user."</Username>
                                        <Password>".$pw."</Password>
                                    </Authentication>
                                    <CountryCode>GBR</CountryCode>
                                    <Person>
                                        <Name>
                                            <Forename>".$firstName."</Forename>
                                            <Surname>".$secondName."</Surname>
                                        </Name>
                                        <DateOfBirth>".$dob."</DateOfBirth>
                                    </Person>
                                    <Addresses>
                                        <Address Current='1'>
                                            <Premise>".$premise."</Premise>
                                            <Street>".$streetName."</Street>
                                            <PostTown>".$postTown."</PostTown>
                                            <Region/>
                                            <Postcode>".$postCode."</Postcode>
                                            <CountryCode>GBR</CountryCode>
                                        </Address>
                                    </Addresses>
                                    <Telephones>
                                        <Telephone>
                                            <Number>".$telephone."</Number>
                                        </Telephone>
                                    </Telephones>
                                    <IPAddress>127.0.0.1</IPAddress>
                                    <Emails>
                                        <Email>".$email."</Email>
                                    </Emails>
                                    <SearchOptions>
                                    <ProductCode>".$product."</ProductCode>
                                    </SearchOptions>
                                </Search>]]>
                            </xml>
                            </cor:search>
                          </soapenv:Body>
                        </soapenv:Envelope>";

       $headers = array(
                    "Content-type: text/xml;charset=\"utf-8\"",
                    "Accept: text/xml",
                    "Cache-Control: no-cache",
                    "Pragma: no-cache",
                    "SOAPAction: https://xml.proveid.experian.com/IDSearch.cfc",
                    "Content-length: ".strlen($xml_post_string),
                );


        $url = $soapUrl;

        // PHP cURL  for https connection with auth
        $ch = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 100);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $xml_post_string); // the SOAP request
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);

        // converting
        $response = curl_exec($ch);
        curl_close($ch);

        print_r($response);`
```

**Response**

```
<Search xmlns:xsd="https://xml.proveid.experian.com/xsd/Search.xsd">
<CountryCode>GBR</CountryCode>
<Person>
    <Name><Forename>Baken</Forename>
        <Surname>Jorure</Surname>
    </Name>
    <DateOfBirth>1989-09-09</DateOfBirth>
    <Age>26</Age>
</Person>
<Addresses>
    <Address Current="1">
        <Premise>410</Premise>
        <Street>Beuno Terrace</Street>
        <PostTown>Beuno</PostTown>
        <Region/>
        <Postcode>LL545BT</Postcode>
        <CountryCode>GBR</CountryCode>
    </Address>
</Addresses>
<Telephones>
    <Telephone>
        <Number>01154567892</Number>
    </Telephone>
</Telephones>
<IPAddress>127.0.0.1</IPAddress>
<Emails>
    <Email>bakenjorure@www.com</Email>
</Emails>
<SearchOptions>
    <ProductCode>ProveID</ProductCode>
</SearchOptions>
<OurReference>B3C369C0-F001-4FB1-80D3-801CB9D872FE</OurReference>
<SearchDate>2015-10-09T23:46:54</SearchDate>
<Result>
    <Summary>
        <ReportSummary>
            <DatablocksSummary>
                <DatablockSummary>
                    <Name>CreditReference</Name>
                    <Decision/>
                </DatablockSummary>
            </DatablocksSummary>
        </ReportSummary>
       <DecisionMatrix Code="ECIGSUAT" Name="Electronic Cigarettes">
           <Decision>
               <Outcome Type="Primary">0</Outcome>
               <Reason>Individuals DOB has not matched to active CAIS 
               ER or Citizen Card therefore application has been 
               referred
               </Reason>
           </Decision>
        </DecisionMatrix>
    </Summary>
    </Result>
</Search>
```

Now all I really need it the number in the Outcome tags. I've tried so many ways but I just can't seem to get it.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For simplier usage of SOAP, you can use PHP builtin SOAP client.
http://php.net/manual/en/class.soapclient.php

With SoapClient class you could do something like this:

```
<?php
    $soapUrl = "https://xml.proveid.experian.com/IDSearch.cfc?wdsl"
    $soapClient = new SoapClient($soapUrl);
    $parameters = array();
    $result = $soapClient->Search($parameters);
?>
```

In result you will get native PHP data structure, not plain text XML as in here.

Comment: Hi @Edvinas thanks for your answer, i did look into writing the request with SOAP client however i kept getting an error response of Invalid XML document. I couldn't seem to grasp how to use multiple elements, Eg. how would i have the <Person></Person> element and the <Address></Address> elements in one array with their children included?

Comment: If you can't use SoapClient ant just would like to parse plain XML you could use SimpleXMLElement.
As I see from your question you need value in Outcome tag, so you could do something like in this example: https://3v4l.org/dhmtW

Comment: Hi @Edvinas thanks for the response. I have managed to extract the data using a slightly different method but you certainly got me on the right path. I ended up encoding to JSON when i eventually extracted the data needed. I believe your answer will help anyone else coming across this!